# Using findOne then save() to replace a document, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use the validation in my schema. Therefore i can't use `findOneAndUpdate` (?). I must use save.

Problem is, if I use findOne, then replaces the object with the one I'm going to replace it with, it will no longer have the save function.

```
mongoose.model('calculations').findOne({calcId:req.params['calcId']}, function(err, calculation){
    if(err) {errHandler.serverErr(err, res, 'Something went wrong when trying to update a calculation'); return;}
    calculation = calculationToReplace;
    calculation.save(function(err, calc){ //No longer exists
      if(err) {errHandler.serverErr(err, res, 'Something went wrong when trying to update a calculation'); return;}
      res.send(200);
    });
  });
```

This must be a common task but I can't find any solution. How do I fix this?

Comment: In English you mean that you "read" an object from the database, but then the object may have "changed" in the database before you write it back. So it should kind of explain why you don't do that and move you logic into the `.findOneAndUpdate()` instead shouldn't it? BTW. Two worst answers given ever.

Comment: Use [replaceOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-replaceOne)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple solution to your (by now really old) question. 
In my case I had to have a findOneAndUpdate upsert that returned more information on what happened. So my solution was to step through the process to update the object with a for loop.

(Think the reason why you can't just copy is that the doc object contains a bunch of "extras" like version information and save function and other "bits"); So here is my solution.

```
exports.postData = function(req,res) {
    console.log("will create " + req.body.alias);
    console.log("It is level " + req.body.level);     //OK, all this have to be changed to members of the data! req.body contains all the data sent from the user at this time
    var query = { 'fulltext' : req.body.fulltext};
    console.log("Checkking if " + req.body.fulltext + " exists")
    Skill.findOne(query, function (err,doc){
        if(err) return res.status(500).send(err)
        if (!doc){
            console.log(req.body.fulltext + " not found!")
            var newdoc = new Skill(req.body);
            newdoc.save(function(err){
                if(err) return res.status(500).send(err)
                console.log(newdoc.fulltext + " created as " + newdoc._id);
                return res.status(200).send({_id: newdoc._id, alias: newdoc.alias})
            })

            return res.status(200).send('blal')
        } else {
            console.log(req.body.fulltext + " found!")
            for (var id in req.body ){
                doc[id]= req.body[id];
            }
            doc.save( function(err){
                if(err) return res.status(500).send(err)
                return res.status(200).send({_id: doc._id, alias: doc.alias})
            })


            //return res.status(200).send({_id: doc._id, alias: doc.alias})
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested the following, so I am not sure if this works properly but it should probably be fine:

Swap this:

```
 calculation = calculationToReplace;
```

with this:

```
 for (var key in calculationToReplace)
   if(typeof calculation[key] !== 'function')
     calculation[key] = calculationToReplace[key];
```

Comment: Unfair of me to place a critique on another anwswer without pointing out how horribly a wrong approach this is. It's basically open to overwriting any updates that occurred in between.

Comment: @NeilLunn If you have a better answer, please share it and I will approve it if I find it better.

Comment: Wrong approach or not it fixes the problem this question was created for: "it will no longer have the save function." Let us know a proper approach you recommend

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. You can read the mongoose documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html). Take a look at the following code.

```
Tank.findById(id, function (err, tank) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  tank.size = 'large';
  tank.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(tank);
  });
});
```

This approach involves first retreiving the document from Mongo, then issuing an update command (triggered by calling save).

Comment: But I want to replace the entire object. Not just one property.

Comment: @PerStröm You have to assign all the properties individually by the way mentioned above. You cannot just replace the whole object.

Comment: @techxxx So I should write 50-60 properties individually? Must be a better way.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry to say this that I got the code from the official documentation of mongoose js and I mentioned the link above. If you have a better approach you can post it.

Comment: The better concept is called `.findOneAndUpdate()` as was mentioned. Anything else is subject to a "race condition" as essentially the data can be modified before it is written back. Really more for @PerStröm to digest as both your answer and the accepted one are not the correct solution. BTW. "I got the code from.." does not make you the person who should answer. If you can only copy with no knowledge then you should not be advising.